# Capitalize first word of a string within parentheses which is also a full sentence?

Tags: capitalization, parentheses

I have a sentence containing a parenthetical which is itself a full sentence. Do I capitalize the first word of the part in the parentheses?

Example:

> The value is estimated by correcting the image for a bead size of 25nm
>   (see above for bead size correction).

or

> The value is estimated by correcting the image for a bead size of 25nm
>   (See above for bead size correction).

Comment: Hmmm. I've wondered about that sometimes too. +1

Comment: Unless it's a complete sentence inside the parentheses or it starts with a proper noun, there's no need for capitalization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sentence(s) can either be written as:

> The value is estimated by correcting the image for a bead size of
>   25nm. (See above for bead size correction.)

or

> The value is estimated by correcting the image for a bead size of 25nm
>   (see above for bead size correction).

According to New [Hart's Rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hart%27s_Rules):

> 'A complete sentence within brackets is capitalized and ends in a full
>   point unless the writer has chosen to place it within another
>   sentence: 
>   "The discussion continued after dinner. (This was
>   inevitable.)" 
>   "The discussion continued after dinner (this was
>   inevitable)."'

If you're going to treat it as two separate sentences, then you need a full point/stop at the end of the previous sentence, and the sentence inside the parentheses must have its own full point/stop ALSO inside the parentheses.

Comment: Thanks for the swift answer. Your reference fully covers my question.

Comment: @Trilarion: that's great - glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rewrite slightly to avoid this.  Either:

> The value is estimated by correcting the image for a bead size of 25nm. See above for bead size correction.

or

> The value is estimated by correcting the image for a bead size of 25nm (see above).

would work.  My sentences can run on a bit anyway, so if I can split out the additional information into a new sentence (because it's already a sentence) I probably should.  Otherwise a shorter form works better.